# Access grpc stream variable for long-running process in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, grpc

I am using Node.js to connect to a server using [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/) that performs a long running task.

The server sends a unidirectional stream to the client (the Node.js app) while the job is in progress. I need to implement a Stop button and am told that closing the [gRPC stream](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/node.html#streaming-rpcs) will stop the job in progress.

This is currently my code:

```js
let express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    grpc = require('grpc'),
    srv = grpc.load(__dirname + '/job_handler.proto').ns;

let startJob = (jobID, parameters) => srv.createJob(jobID, parameters);

router.post('/jobs', (req, res) => {
    let lengthyOperation = startJob(jobID, parameters);
    lengthyOperation.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`Data from lengthy operation: ${data}`);
    });

    lengthyOperation.on('end', () =>
        console.log('Lengthy operation completed');
    });

    res.setHeader('Location', `/jobs/${jobID}`);
    res.status(202).send();
});
```

As you can see, I send an [HTTP 202](https://httpstatuses.com/202) response to the client upon creating the job and it continues asynchronously in the background.

Questions:

1. How do I close the stream?
2. How do I access the `lengthyOperation` variable to do so?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. What trouble are you having with accessing that object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lengthyOperation` object has a `cancel` method that cancels the call. So, when you want to stop the stream, just call `lengthyOperation.cancel()`.

Note that when you do this, it will cause the call to end with an error. I would recommend adding a `lengthyOperation.on('error', ...)` handler to handle that error.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access the `lengthyOperation` variable from another request if it only lives inside that request?

Comment: I guess you'll have to put it in a scope or attach it to an object in a scope that is accessible from that other request.